# Swing popup in a Swing Application

Tags: java, swing

I have a Swing UI with certain number of buttons. One button invokes a separate swing class and a new window is opened with new buttons and other features. Now when I am closing this window the original window is also getting closed. 
I think this is because both the classes have impemented

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
//some code
}
}
```

Now how to overcome this? A code example or link will be very helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Why this question was down-voted is beyond me. Up-voted to undo down-vote.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels-Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is hard to guess without seeing the code. Perhaps your `JFrame` has `setDefaultCloseOperation` set to close the application when the window is closed (maybe `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`). Have a look at [the java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) for more info on this.

From [the java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29):

> `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` (defined in `JFrame`): Exit the application using the `System exit` method. Use this only in applications.

This means that the whole application will close. You do not want that for the second window. You just want the window (not the application) to close.

Comment: Yes both the code has setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE), but it is for that individual window to close. how it is affecting the mother frame?

Comment: @JavaBits - don't assume, guess, or invent behaviour (or however you came up with the incorrect "individual window" stuff), instead read the api doc carefully (as already suggested)

Comment: @kleopatra - its not possible to read the documentation always. Else we can use this platform to share the problems . i guess thats y this platform was created in the first place.

Comment: @JavaBits - if you cant read the documentation always, something is wrong with the setup of your local work environment: javadoc is the first and most simple to check resource. As far as I'm concerned, I _expect_ developers to first check before asking anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater` has no relation to an application closing. Its purpose is to defer the `run` method invocation to when the GUI thread has finished painting and processing current events.

I suggest you to check your code for `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` as was already suggested and also for `System.exit()` calls.

To answer the comment, since you set `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` on both frames, it is the expected behaviour to exit the whole application when you close any of the frames. See [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29).

To solve your problem, you need to remove this `setDefaultCloseOperation` on the second frame.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others, calling your code on the main Swing thread, the EDT or Event Dispatch Thread, by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` has nothing to do with your problem, and in fact is a good habit of getting in to *if* there's a risk that by not doing this your code could be called off of the EDT. In other words, if you're showing your other window from code called in a JButton's ActionListener, then there's no need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` since the actionPerformed method will be called on the EDT.

Getting back to your problem at hand, I suggest that you make the other window a JDialog -- either modal to the application or not, depending on your need -- rather than a JFrame. Doing this allows you to keep the dialog above the main JFrame and allows you to force the user to deal with your dialog before going back to the main GUI, and prevents the application from closing if the dialog closes.

And to answer your likely next question, yes, JDialogs can hold complex GUI's, as complex as any JFrame.

Comment: Can i add buttons and text areas in JDialog?

Comment: @JavaBits yes same way as to JFrame for more info look here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html and don't forget to look for toFront(), setAlwaysOnTop() and Modalities for JDialog, and try to reuse one JDialog,  just replace its contents, Hovercraft Full Of Eels +1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` on the parent JFrame.

`setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` will terminate the application when the last JFrame is closed whereas `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` will terminate the application as soon as that JFrame is closed.